# How to use markdown code highlighting for Liquid in JekyllRB?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, rouge

Using JekyllRB/Rouge, how does one highlight (but not interpret) Liquid code within a markdown file?

IE:

I have a markdown file with:

````
Blah blah blah, my cool post... here's some code:

```liquid
{% assign variableName = 'test' %}
```
````

In the resulting HTML, I'd like to see the actual code, without Jekyll interpreting it within the markdown file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Make use of the `{% raw %}` Liquid tag.

IE:

````
```
{% raw %}
  {{ somevariablewewanttoshow }}
{% endraw %}
```
````